# Terminal app can access folders that it isn't allowed

Tags: terminal, security, privacy

In the security and privacy pane I didn't allow the terminal app to access anything.

[image: Privacy setting]

I didn't allow full disk access either.

However, it can show the contents of Desktop by doing `cd Desktop`, `ls`. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first question is: why would you do that to your terminal.app?

To answer your question. Terminal.app is automatically granted Full Disk Access by default and it does not show up in the Full Disk Access tab on the Security Pane.

You can see this by running the following in your term:

`sudo sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db 'select * from access'`

I hope it answers your question.

Comment: if Terminal.app has Full Disk Access by default, why does it ask for other permissions?

Comment: It did not on my computer... Just got MBA2020 with M1 chip and Big Sur.

Comment: Terminal shows up with Full Disk Acces on my M1 mini, but when prompted I might well have given full access

Comment: What does that command do? If I edit the file `Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db`, can I disable Full Disk Access?

Comment: To be honest with you, if you don't understand the command above, don't go any further. You could seriously harm your system... 

To answer your question: `sudo` gives you the root access to your computer (God's power), `sqlite3` is a program for reading/writing databases files like `TCC.db`. You could maybe disable the Full Disk Access manually using `sqlite3`. I still don't understand why you would do that to your terminal.

Comment: @NiborNdj I didn't answer your question... I want to know how to protect my privacy from apps (mainly third party apps) and searching how to configure permissions. I was wondering why terminal apps can access folders that I did not allow in the Security & Privacy pane. Now I understand that some permissions are not listed there.

Comment: The short answer is that apple’s terminal app is mainly a low-level user application. It can entirely replace Finder for navigation in your folder but also running commands. 

Apple’s terminal is developed by Apple, it does not violate your privacy more than any other Apple’s app. This security system is made for external developers apps. Exemple, to prevent a photo app to access your emails or some critical folders on your disk.

Comment: To go more into the details, macOS is a Unix based system. If your are worried than other users of your computer could visit your folders via the terminal, you are not looking in the right place. You should look at Unix Permissions instead ;)

Answer (score 1):

[`tccutil`](https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/tccutil.1.html) can be used to reset decisions about whether apps may access a folder.

Remove Terminal from Full Disk Access and Files and Folder.

```
tccutil reset All com.apple.Terminal
```

Afterwards listing the directory contents of the Desktop folder results in an access request.

```
ls ~/Desktop
```

[image: "Terminal" would like to access files in your Desktop folder]